# Error in Creating stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Anybody tell me what's wrong with creating this stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROC ImportData
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @DatabasePath VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @DatabasePath = 'E:\ABC.xls'

    DECLARE @sql      nvarchar(MAX)
    SET @sql = '
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]
    SELECT  *
    FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'',
            ''Excel 8.0;Database=' + @DatabasePath + ',
            ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'') AS xlsTable'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    GO

END

ERROR:-
Incorrect syntax near '@sql'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.
```

Comment: Any particular database engine, or will you be happy with random guesses?

Comment: The database engine I guess your using requires all literal strings to be written in Klingon. Also, get rid of the "go." and dynamic SQL sucks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the GO from within the Stored Procedure

Something like

```
CREATE PROC ImportData 
AS 
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @DatabasePath VARCHAR(MAX) 
    SET @DatabasePath = 'E:\ABC.xls' 

    DECLARE @sql      nvarchar(MAX) 
    SET @sql = ' 
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1] 
    SELECT  * 
    FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'', 
            ''Excel 8.0;Database=' + @DatabasePath + ', 
            ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'') AS xlsTable' 

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql 

END
```

Comment: Can u explain reason behind it.

Comment: In SSMS Go is a statement terminator/batch terminator. So when you try to execute the create statement, sql server tries to parse the script and fails.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a batch terminator (`GO`) in the body of a stored procedure.